# List of FAQs and canonical posts

Tags: discussion, canonical-question

Based on the recent question:

[Let's change the canonical question about forming possessives for words which end in 'z' [Completed]](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9815/lets-change-the-canonical-question-about-forming-possessives-for-words-which-en)

and its predecessor:

[Please change the canonical 'ordinal question' to one which is more informative](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6934/55623)

I'm wondering: is there a list of FAQs and/or canonical posts, for ease of reference when closing as duplicate?

If there is such a list, please close this question as a dupe of that question (I'll delete it after).

If there is no such list, let's use this thread to create one.

Answers to this question should be of the form "Here's the canonical question on X", where *canonical* means "all future questions in X not sufficiently differentiated in their details should be closed as duplicates of that".

Comment: Do you intend ultimately to turn this list into a main site FAQ tag?

Comment: @MetaEd I'm not really familiar with the main-site FAQ tag, but doesn't that have to be curated by mods? Or is there a way for the community to curate it?  Sincerely, I've never used it.

Comment: I don't know the answer. Right now I believe there isn't one. I think your question is a good argument for creating one, but being the "new guy" I could also be quite wrong.

Comment: A quick search suggests that on StackExchange, "FAQs" are about the *operation* of the site (Meta stuff, like "what is close-voting"), and *canonical posts* are the kinds of things collected in this thread. There was a suggestion on Meta to support a `[canonical]` tag, but it was stillborn. Other sites, e.g. GIS, [maintain Meta-questions collecting canonical posts](http://meta.gis.stackexchange.com/questions/3620/do-we-need-a-list-of-canonical-questions), so I'm currently thinking this question is the way to go.

Comment: Super User on the other hand does do it with a tag: http://superuser.com/questions/tagged/community-faq

Comment: @MetaEd I thought "Meta tags" like "homework" or "community FAQ" were verboten. Anyway, I checked Math.se, and they also keep MetaQ with a list. Though I'm now thinking I'll have to use the key of a Q as an index to organize the answers.

Comment: Apparently they are, except when they're not.

Comment: @MetaEd I’ve always considered the [ELU Frequent Questions list](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions?sort=frequent) to be our secret FAQ, the one nobody knows about.

Comment: @tchrist That looks like front page to me. I can't see what the organizing principle is.

Comment: @DanBron It's sorted by the dup count.

Comment: We should link to this question from the [blog](http://english.blogoverflow.com/) or some other easily-accessible place such as the [help pages](http://english.stackexchange.com/help).

Answer (score 5):

#### Basic questions on differences in tenses and aspects in English

> [How do the tenses and aspects in English correspond temporally to one another?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/21846/how-do-the-tenses-and-aspects-in-english-correspond-temporally-to-one-another)

Comment: I think the list of answers is getting pretty long. Perhaps we should consolidate them into a smaller number of answers on broader topics (like "choosing X over Y" or "tenses", or whatever)? We could also change the Q to be an index to the As.

Comment: @DanBron I agree it is too long. That's what I was worried about when I started to post the answers here. But this really helps me to find duplicates. I think the answers should be put together under some categories such as tense / verb agreement / noun (pronoun) / possessive, etc... Let me think about it and try to merge some answers.

Comment: sounds good.  It's probably better to use the questions which are upvoted and not posted by me as the containers for categories, because I can delete any answer I posted, and upvoted answers will be more visible (and harder to delete).

Answer (score 4):

#### General neutral pronouns

- Can I use the "singular they"?
- What is a gender-neutral way to refer to a single individual?

> [Is there a correct gender-neutral singular pronoun ("his" vs. "her" vs. "their")?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/48/is-there-a-correct-gender-neutral-singular-pronoun-his-versus-her-versus)

Comment: Also highly upvoted is the older *[Is it correct to use “their” instead of “his or her”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/192)*

Answer (score 4):

#### Ordering adjectives

- Is it great green dragon or green great dragon?

> [What is the rule for adjective order?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1155/what-is-the-rule-for-adjective-order)

Answer (score 3):

#### Forming possessives

- How do we form a possessive for a word which ends in an `s`?
- How about a `z`?
- What if it's a surname?

> [Possessive form for a surname ending with "z"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/343943/possessive-form-for-a-surname-ending-with-z)

- *Giant Ostrich Bomb's (GOB) fuse* or *Giant Ostrich Bomb (GOB)'s fuse*?
- *Pendleton, et al. (2002)’s research*

> [How do I correctly use the possessive apostrophe with a parenthetical citation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13600)
>   [Where should the apostrophe go on a possessive abbreviation?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/332392)

Answer (score 3):

## Writing compound nouns

- Should I write "nounnoun", "noun-noun" or "noun noun"?

> [When should compound words be written as one word, with hyphens, or with spaces?](https://english.stackexchange.com/q/889/59258)

Answer (score 2):

#### Compound possessives incorporating the first person

> ["My wife and I's seafood collaboration dinner"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4226)

Also upvoted, but now marked as duplicates of the first:

> [How do you make the possessive form with "He and I"-style subjects?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38847)
>   [What possessive forms are used for mutual 1st person ownership?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/8520)

Comment: Although, I think this first one is not ideal as a "canonical post", and it seems some other people agreed with me: [Can we switch to a better canonical question about using pronouns in compound possessives?](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/7109)

Answer (score 2):

**Difference between verb + preposition and phrasal verbs**

For example: look for something vs look something up (something).

> [Difference between verb+preposition and phrasal verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/112646/difference-between-verbpreposition-and-phrasal-verbs)

Answer (score 1):

#### Basic questions on differences between Present Perfect and Past Simple

> [Present perfect for past action with present effect](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/57869/present-perfect-for-past-action-with-present-effect)

and

> [Which is correct: “has died” or “died”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/63256/which-is-correct-has-died-or-died)

Answer (score 1):

#### How many spaces after a period?

- Should I use one space or two after a period?
- Is it ok to use just one space after a period?

> [How many spaces should come after a period/full stop?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2544/how-many-spaces-should-come-after-a-period-full-stop)

Comment: I'm all for this to be a canonical question, but arguably it should be a *closed* canonical question.

Comment: @curiousdannii Go ahead and VtC. I got this one by going to the list of Qs and sorting by votes....

Answer (score 1):

#### When do I used *who* vs *whom*

> [What’s the rule for using “who” and “whom” correctly?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56/what-s-the-rule-for-using-who-and-whom-correctly)

Answer (score 1):

#### When do I use *that* vs *which*?

> [When to use “that” and when to use “which”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/78/when-to-use-that-and-when-to-use-which)

Answer (score 1):

#### When should I use *a* vs *an*?

> [When should I use "a" vs "an"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/152/when-should-i-use-a-vs-an)

Comment: The most popular duplicate target is currently *[Are there any simple rules for choosing the definite vs. indefinite (vs. none) article?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2031)*, though sumelic's answer in the cited question is arguably the most complete.

Comment: @choster It's a wiki, I encourage everyone to make any edits they see fit.

Comment: Right, but I'm only adding supplemental information; as I noted, I find the question you found the superior one.

Answer (score 1):

#### Singular or plural agreement with collective nouns

- *The team is here* or *The team are here*?

> [Are collective nouns always plural, or are certain ones singular?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1338)

Where coupled with a dummy subject, see

> ["There is/are more than one". What's the difference?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/35389)
> ["There are no shortage of applications"](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/290856)

Answer (score 1):

#### Backshifting and reported speech

> [Problem with backshift in reporting clauses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/240479/problem-with-backshift-in-reporting-clauses)

Answer (score 1):

**When to use Present Continuous (Progressive) for future actions?**

> [When do I use Present Continuous for near future instead of “be going to”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/235368/when-do-i-use-present-continuous-for-near-future-instead-of-be-going-to)

Answer (score 1):

**Using do for emphasis / Why do you use "do" before another verb?**

**Do-support for emphasis**

> [“did shoot” vs “shot”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/323/did-shoot-vs-shot)

Answer (score 1):

**"If I were" vs "If I was"**

**When do you use "were" after if and which is correct between "were" and "was"?**

> [“If I was” or “If I were”. Which is more common, and which is correct?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/660/if-i-was-or-if-i-were-which-is-more-common-and-which-is-correct)

Answer (score 1):

### Gerund vs. infinitive for verb complements

- *My favorite pastime is to cook* vs. *My favorite pastime is cooking*
- *Try to rotate your knee* vs. *Try rotating your knee*

> [When should a verb be followed by a gerund instead of an infinitive?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/329)

Answer (score 0):

#### Forming questions to elicit ordinal numbers as a response

- How do I ask a question about Abraham Lincoln's position in the sequence of US presidents to elicit **sixteenth** or **16th** as a response?

> [Framing a question whose answer is an ordinal number](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/11481/framing-a-question-whose-answer-is-an-ordinal-number)

Comment: The meta community chose a different canonical question here (including you it seems, by Mari-Lou A's thanking of you!): http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/q/6934/59258

Comment: @curiousdannii Thanks. I thought I picked up the right Q from that thread, I did go looking for it... anyway, all the answers here are community wiki for a reason. The community part is sincere, I mean it. If I got any of these wrong today, or the answers change tomorrow, you and everyone else should feel entitled, fearlessly entitled, to edit them yourselves.

Comment: Sure thing, I will edit away if I see any more!

Answer (score 0):

#### When should I use a hyphen vs en-dash vs em-dash?

> [When should I use an em-dash, an en-dash, and a hyphen?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2116/when-should-i-use-an-em-dash-an-en-dash-and-a-hyphen)